# Custom Customer Account Tab

Tags: magento-1.9, module, customer-account

I am following [Alan Storms documentation to add a custom tab to accounts page](http://alanstorm.com/magento_create_customer_page) but unfortunately I am running into a hiccup. I am not able to route and load my controller when I click on my custom link tab within accounts. I can definitely add the custom tab but routing the url once I click on it is not doing anything. Running version 1.9.0.1

> app/code/community/Brandster/CustomAccount/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <frontend>
    <layout>
      <updates>
        <brandster_customaccount module="Brandster_CustomAccount">
            <file>brandster_customaccount.xml</file>
        </brandster_customaccount>
      </updates>
    </layout>
    <routers>
      <brandster_customaccount>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
          <module>Brandster_CustomAccount</module>
          <frontName>brandster_customaccount</frontName>
        </args>
      </brandster_customaccount>
    </routers>
  </frontend>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <brandster_customaccount>
        <class>Brandster_CustomAccount_Helper</class>
      </brandster_customaccount>
    </helpers>
  </global>
</config>
```

> app/design/frontend/mytheme/mypackage/layout/brandster_customaccount.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
  <customer_account>
    <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
      <action method="addLink">
        <name>our_new_section</name>
        <path>brandster_customaccount/index/index</path>
        <label>Terms &amp; Conditions</label>
      </action>
    </reference>
  </customer_account>
  <brandster_customaccount_index_index>
    <update handle="customer_account" />
  </brandster_customaccount_index_index>
</layout>
```

> app/code/community/Brandster/CustomAccount/Controllers/IndexController.php

```
<?php
class Brandster_CustomAccount_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
public function preDispatch()
  {
    parent::preDispatch();
    $action = $this->getRequest()->getActionName();
    $loginUrl = Mage::helper('customer')->getLoginUrl();

    if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->authenticate($this, $loginUrl)) {
      $this->setFlag('', self::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
    }
  }
}
```

> app/code/community/Brandster/CustomAccount/Helper/Data.php

```
<?php
class Brandster_CustomAccount_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is actually fine, you simply miss an `indexAction()` method in your controller. Just add

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

to `app/code/community/Brandster/CustomAccount/controllers/IndexController.php`. Please note that the folder should be named `controllers` and not `Controllers`, otherwise Magento won't find your class.

Comment: WOW.. thanks for catching those two errors, I have corrected it as you stated but still no success rendering I get the 404 page with an error in the url  `errors/report.php?id=1011755426413&skin=default`

Comment: You can find the details of the error under `var/report/1011755426413`

Comment: Man I cant thank you enough! Magento being so huge is intimidating tending to overlook some simple mistakes. I resolved the issue for the error turns out I had unnecessary white space and I made sure I closed my PHP tag.